# WebAPI throttling best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, throttling

I am looking for advice on best practices while using this WebAPI throttling library.

Is there a way to reuse same rule for all clients in WebAPI throttling (https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle) ?

Our current setup has one rule / json entry per client in the throttle policy. Whenever a new device is added a new client rule is added to the list and the entire policy is updated.

```
{
  "IpThrottling": false,
  "IpWhitelist": [],
  "IpRules": {

  },
  "ClientThrottling": true,
  "ClientWhitelist": [],
  "ClientRules": {
    "common_policy": {
      "PerSecond": 0,
      "PerMinute": 0,
      "PerHour": 0,
      "PerDay": 1000,
      "PerWeek": 0
    },
    "Client-1": {
      "PerSecond": 0,
      "PerMinute": 0,
      "PerHour": 0,
      "PerDay": 1000,
      "PerWeek": 0
    },
    "Client-35": {
      "PerSecond": 0,
      "PerMinute": 0,
      "PerHour": 0,
      "PerDay": 1000,
      "PerWeek": 0
    },
    .
    .
    .
  },
  "EndpointThrottling": true,
  "EndpointWhitelist": [],
  "EndpointRules": {

  },
  "StackBlockedRequests": false,
  "Rates": {
    "Second": 0,
    "Minute": 0,
    "Hour": 0,
    "Day": 0,
    "Week": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: I bet that library thing stores all these request counts in memory cache by default. So, as soon as IIS restarts(daily) or app pool stops (20 mins w/ no activity by default) that counter will be reset back to 0. Its definitely something to consider. Best practice? @least make sure u r storing stuff in the db or something.

Comment: @HirasawaYui, we actually use Redis as our data store, so we are covered in that aspect. I was looking for advice for best practice to maintain policies.

Comment: After some digging, found the solution. We can set base line rates at the "Rates" element of the policy. Once that is set, it applies for everyone. The ClientRules/EndpointRules/IpRules provide finer control based on relevant situations.